# When I implement FCNs using MITSceneParsing data, I got this error [TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, pickle

I used MITSceneParsing data when I implement Fully Convolutional Networks. But I got this error [TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable]. So anybody knows this reason?

```
import pickle

def read_dataset(data_dir):
    pickle_filename = "MITSceneParsing.pickle"
    pickle_filepath = os.path.join(data_dir, pickle_filename)
    if not os.path.exists(pickle_filepath):
        utils.maybe_download_and_extract(data_dir, DATA_URL, is_zipfile=True)
        SceneParsing_folder = os.path.splitext(DATA_URL.split("\\")[-1])[0]
        result = create_image_lists(os.path.join(data_dir, SceneParsing_folder))
        print("Pickling...")
        with open(pickle_filepath, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(result, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    else:
        print("Found pickle file!")

    with open(pickle_filepath, 'rb') as f:
        result = pickle.load(f)
        training_records = result['training']
        validation_records = result['validation']
        del result

    return training_records, validation_records
```

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the stack trace.